Branch cuts of a periodic function
Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $0<s<1$, and define,
$$
f(z) = (1-\cos z)^s.
$$
Therefore, we have infinite branch points of the form $2\pi k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I have three questions:

Is it valid to remove $\mathbb{R} $ in order to have all the branch cuts taken out at once? Is this the normal way to proceed?

Imagine you want to cross the real line for an integral, maybe between $\pi - i$ and $\pi + i$. The first choice of the branch doesn't allow it. Can we instead define, for example, the branches to be the rays
$$
R_k =\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re z = 2k\pi \text{ and } \Im z \in (-\infty,0)\}
$$
to allow the integration path?


The motivation of this question comes from this post.
